# I can't create user in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I try to create a user by using `ldapadd` command line but the user can't be added

```
ldapadd -x  -H ldap://ip:389 -D "cn=iib,cn=users,dc=ldap,dc=local" -w P@ssw0rd@! -f newentry.ldif   
adding new entry "cn=John.Doe,OU=Users,DC=ldap,DC=local"
```

> ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
> Additional info: 0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A124C, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0

`newentry.ldif`:

```
dn: cn=John.Doe,ou=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: users
cn: John Doe
givenName: John
sn: Doe
mail: jdoe@mydomain.com
userPassword: {SHA}nU4ibzI1wtmKj+FRn4mHSg== 
--
```

Comment: The problem is likely the password. Read this, under "The User LDIF": http://pig.made-it.com/pig-adusers.html#:~:text=2147483647-,The%20User%20LDIF,-To%20create%20users